# How do I assign an integer to an enum field?

Tags: java

A class (*Card*) has an enum field. I encapsulate the enum type definition as private within the class:

```
private enum Suit {
    HEARTS, DIAMONDS, SPADES, CLUBS;
}
```

In the constructor I want to assign a random suit to a card. Of course, I could create a switch-case statement on the next discrete uniform variate and branch on four different values. Something tells me that there is a more compact way to do this. In C, an enum value is just an integer, but

```
public Card() {
    this.suit = this.random.nextInt(4);
}
```

(where this.suit is of type Suit) doesn't work in Java because of type conflict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
Suit.values()[indexHere];
```

The `values()` method gives the enums in an array, in the same order as you wrote them in the code. This method is automatically added by the compiler.

So, in your case:

```
public Card()
{
    this.suit = Suit.values()[this.random.nextInt(4)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Card() {
    this.suit = Suit.values()[new Random().nextInt(Suit.values().length)];
}
```

Comment: Almost the same of @Martijin answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not fast enough

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Suit.values()[(int) (Math.random() * 4);
```